# Icons on JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, icons, joptionpane

Sorry, this is really basic. My first experience with Java Swing using Eclipse. I'm trying to write a very simple `JOptionPane`. I want the question mark icon to appear, but all I am getting is the Java coffee cup icon. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
Object[] options = {"Encrypt", "Decrypt"};

int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(),
                "What Do You Want to Do?",
        "Crypto",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null,     //do not use a custom Icon
        options,  //the titles of buttons
        options[0]); //default button title
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use this one instead http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon%29 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Try with different themes

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");

                // Set Motif L&F on any platform
                // UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");

                // Set cross-platform Java L&F (also called "Metal")
                // UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());

                // Set System L&F
                //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            Object[] options = { "Encrypt", "Decrypt" };

            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(), "What Do You Want to Do?", "Crypto",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, // do not use a
                                                                                   // custom Icon
                    options, // the titles of buttons
                    options[0]); // default button title
        }
    });
```

With different themes:

[image]
[image]
[image]